# SharedPreferences - Must you use strings.xml file with a custom SharedPref class?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I set up SharedPreferences by following android documentation, requiring me to add each category to a string such as:

```
<string name="date_of_birth">com.test.activity.dateOfBirth</string>
```

But since I required a decent amount of variables to be stored and accessed from different activities, I created a class to handle SharedPreferences by following the guide here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40446531/11019416

Have each variable defined in the SharedPref class as:

```
public static final String DATE_OF_BIRTH = "com.test.activity.dateOfBirth";
```

Calling the class in the relevant activity:

```
SharedPref.init(getApplicationContext());
```

Writing the necessary data to SharedPreferences:

```
 String DATE_OF_BIRTH = eDateOfBirth.getText().toString();
                    SharedPref.write(SharedPref.DATE_OF_BIRTH, DATE_OF_BIRTH);
```

When I test retrieving the data in the next activity by changing a textview field to the DATE_OF_BIRTH variable, I get "com.test.activity.dateOfBirth" as a result instead of the date.

I have tried not using any predefined strings in strings.xml, along with saving the strings as different names, but cannot get it to save correctly.

Am I correctly using strings.xml with this? Or should the content of each string be blank?

Comment: Have you checked this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @isaaaaame Yes I did, but it didn't clarify the setting of strings in the xml file. I didn't have rep to comment, but I guess my question is do I set the SharedPreferences 'key' name as the name of the string, or the content of the string?